# How do I color an image using an array of selected colors in Unity?

Tags: arrays, image, unity-game-engine

I have an image that I am trying to set a random color.

```
 public Color teamAColor;

 public void Start() {
     teamAColor = new Color (0, 1, 0, 1);

     Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image> ();
    scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;
 }
```

This works fine.

```
 public Color teamAColor;

 public void Start() {
     teamAColor = new Color (Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1);
     Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image> ();
    scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;
 }
```

This also works fine.

```
public Color teamAColor;

public Color[] teamAColors = new Color[4];

public void Start() {
   teamAColor = teamAColors [Random.Range (0, teamAColors.Length)];
     Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image> ();
    scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;

   {
        //Team A Colors
        teamAColors [0] = new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1);
        teamAColors [1] = new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1);
        teamAColors [2] = new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1);
        teamAColors [3] = new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.  It doesn't pull in any color.  The strange part is I am using the same code to color animations, which does work.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your start code, you can't access the colors because you haven't built the array yet, you need to build the array before access it, try this instead:

```
public Color teamAColor;
public Color[] teamAColors = new Color[4];

public void Start() {
    //Team A Colors
    teamAColors [0] = new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1);
    teamAColors [1] = new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1);
    teamAColors [2] = new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1);
    teamAColors [3] = new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1);

    teamAColor = teamAColors [Random.Range (0, teamAColors.Length)];
    Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image> ();
    scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;
}
```

but you could also initialize the values outside of the start function(i.e. giving them default value) by doing this:

```
public Color[] teamAColors = new Color[] {new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1),
                                          new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1),
                                          new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1),
                                          new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1) };
```

instead of assigning the values in the Start() function.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it works for me. Just put some Debug.Log to address the issue.

```
public void Start() {
    teamAColor = teamAColors[Random.Range(0, teamAColors.Length)];
    Debug.Log("Selected color: " + teamAColor);
    Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image>();
    Debug.Log("Image object: " + scoreBoardRed);
    Debug.Log("Default Image color:" + scoreBoardRed.color);
    scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;
    Debug.Log("New Image color: " + scoreBoardRed.color);

   {
        //Team A Colors
        teamAColors [0] = new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1);
        teamAColors [1] = new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1);
        teamAColors [2] = new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1);
        teamAColors [3] = new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  I was messing around with it and all i needed to do was remove the {} brackets.  Thanks for the help!